# Duplicate identifier in typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I have a small typescript app which is composed of 4-5 typescript files. One of these files is called `interfaces.ts` and I use this to define internal data structures I'm using.

In many cases, the attributes in these interfaces are giving errors that they have "duplicate identifiers" which I'm sure isn't literally true as this is my own code and I have double checked that I didn't accidentally reproduce this. Also, it appears that those properties which have errors have references to the property but that shouldn't matter, right? Here's an example:

[image: interface]

And in this example, the `id`, `fileStatus`, and `externalParties` properties have more than one reference to them. See below for `fileStatus`:

[image: fileStatus references]

But I've also just noticed that the `name` property (which is without error) also has multiple references (so the reference theory may be a red herring):

[image: name references]

Any help on explaining this would make me feel a lot saner.

> p.s. error or not the syntactic sugar and the transpilation to JS works without any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> references to the property but that shouldn't matter, right

Indeed references don't matter. However you should actually trigger a `goto definition` to see all the places where it is defined.

WARNING: might be a vscode bug *especially* if your project has multiple tsconfig.json files.

Comment: Yeah your suggestion makes perfect sense. Not sure why I didn't think of that but I went back to try and to my surprise the errors are now all gone. I haven't really made any substantial changes.

Comment: Hence vscode bug. I wrote my an IDE for TypeScript so all bugs would be my own http://alm.tools/ :)